# How to specify a route prefix in OData for onbound functions in a IEdmModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I'm migrating a ASP.NET application to ASP.NET Core. I'm having trouble to properly migrate unbound functions in OData. This code is based on the [ODataRoutingSample](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/9225d1eba1601bf1470b7e611cdd595fa479dbfc/sample).

Startup

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllers().AddOData( opt => opt.AddRouteComponents( "my_route_prefix", GetEdmModel() ) );
    }

    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app )
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseODataRouteDebug();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints( endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers() );
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>( "Products" );

        var unboundFunction = builder.Function( "CalculateSalary" ).Returns<string>();
        unboundFunction.Parameter<int>( "minSalary" );

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Controller

```cs
public class ProductsController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok( new List<Product>() { new Product() { Id = 1, Category = "Foo" } } );
    }

    [HttpGet( "CalculateSalary(minSalary={min})" )]
    public string CalculateSalary( int min )
    {
        return $"Unbound function call on CalculateSalary: min={min}";
    }
}
```

Currently the route for the unbound function is `~/CalculateSalary(minSalary={min})`. The route prefix `my_route_prefix` gets ignored.

**How can I configure the route for all unbound functions in a `IEdmModel` to `~/my_route_prefix/CalculateSalary(minSalary={min})`?**

The only way I found is to prepend the prefix in every `HttpGet` attribute of every unbound function:

```cs
[HttpGet( "my_route_prefix/CalculateSalary(minSalary={min})" )]
```